# Get Incorrect test coverage during Vue.js unit test

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, webpack, mocha.js, karma-runner

I'm trying Vuejs unit test using karma+mocha+chai+webpack and get code coverage with istanbul.

Here's the issue, when I import some utils function or some other component in my component to be tested, the code coverage I got will include those utils code.This is not what I want.

In the component I want to test :

```
// src/home/mod_setting/upgrade_management/common/uploader.vue

import FileUploader from 'src/components/file_upload/index';
import Uploader from './uploader';
import logger from 'src/util/logger';
```

The coverage report will include these files.
[image]

### Is there a solution ?

Comment: But the coverage is not incorrect.

Comment: I just want it to show the component's coverage excluding those util files imported by the component.@ThomasKleßen

Comment: The reason you want to achieve this is a high code coverage score. But that would be a lie. Just live with the lower score. As far as i know there is no resonable way to exclude files from istanbul reports. At least some time ago i tried the same and gave up. From that point on i just accept the lower coverage score

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by affecting the 'preprocessor' entry in your karma conf : only files matching this will be monitored for coverage.

See following issue > https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/issues/13

In your case something like

```
preprocessor: { 'src/!(util)/**/*.js' : 'coverage' }
```

should do the trick